# Mislabeled graph on Careers candidate search

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

"One of these things is not like the other, one of these things just doesn't belong..."

[image: careers candidate search graphs]

The graph changes depending on what you [search for](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/candidate-search), so presumably it's pulling real data from somewhere. Unfortunately without the proper labels, I can only assume it's the candidates' favourite colours.

Comment: I thought they were just being funny :)

Comment: haha, my guess is it is just a static image.  That looks way too close to 25%/75% for me.

Comment: @jjnguy The image does change to something less "regular", I guess I could have picked a better screenshot.

Comment: oh.  Never mind my above comment then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The designer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin)'s mockup had 4 pie charts, but we only came up with 3 real ones before the conversation devolved into joke ideas (total elapsed time: about 30 seconds).

Comment: In that case I'm surprised it's not just a 100% chunk labeled "bacon".

Comment: So, was the joke "Preferred color of prison jumpsuit to wear after assaulting a team member who breaks the build"?